# Reading multiple Excel files, averaging, and writing to a single Excel file in Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

I am trying to expand some code I've written. It might be useful to include that script below:

```
% importing single excel sheet

data = xlsread('test_file.xlsx');

% averaging durations (exluding NaNs)

average_rx_time = mean(reaction_time, 'omitnan');
average_reach_dur = mean(reach_dur, 'omitnan');
average_lift_dur = mean(lift_dur, 'omitnan');
average_hold_dur = mean(hold_dur, 'omitnan');
average_withdrawal_dur = mean(withdrawal_dur, 'omitnan');

% Excel file output containing daily averages

a = [average_rx_time, average_reach_dur, average_lift_dur, average_hold_dur, average_withdrawal_dur];
data_cells = num2cell(a);
column_headers ={'Rx Time', 'Reach Dur', 'Lift Dur', 'Hold Dur', 'Withdrawal Dur'};
row_headers(1,1) ={'Day 1'};
output = [{' '} column_headers; row_headers data_cells];
xlswrite('Test.xls', output);
```

This portion works. It reads a bunch of values in a single Excel sheet, averages some numbers, then prints those averages to another Excel sheet. What I need to do now is read several files from a directory (they all exist in one folder and are the same file type), average the same values in each file, then print them with their respective file name in the spreadsheet.

I think I should use a loop, but I'm not sure where to implement it. I'm also not sure how to read multiple Excel files while printing to the same one. Any ideas?

Thanks, 
Mickey

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`cd`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cd.html) and [`dir`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) functions to get a list of files in a specified folder:

```
cd('\path\to\folder');    % set MATLAB's current folder
fileList = dir('*.xlsx'); % get list of .xlsx files in a struct array

for fileNum = 1:length(fileList)
    fileName = fileList(fileNum).name;

    % do whatever you want with fileName here

end
```